# SQL Server : trigger stops working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I created a trigger on a table, my first ever.

When a record is inserted to my TableA, the trigger will insert a new record to the same TableA.

1. When I insert a record that meets the conditions set in the statement, the trigger is properly actioned.
2. When I insert a record that does not meet those conditions, the trigger is not actioned.
3. Problem is that if I now add again a new record that meets conditions, the trigger is not actioned anymore. It seems to stop working when I insert a record that does not meet conditions.

If I deleted the record added in point 2, where conditions are not met, then it starts working again. Weird, can't understand. Any suggestions, please?

Scenario: when a customer buys for the 1st time an item that belongs to a `StockType=1`, then a new product will be added to the same invoice. It works fine.

If a customer buys a different product, that does not belong to `StockType=1`, then the trigger is not actioned. And this fine.

After that, the trigger will not be actioned ever again. Here is the original statement code.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;    
DECLARE @SerialNo NVARCHAR(50)

    SET @SerialNo = (SELECT TOP 1 SNSerialNoTx 
                     FROM T_SNSerialNo 
                     WHERE (SNStockItemID = 7058 AND SNInvoiceID_N IS NULL))

    INSERT INTO T_IIInvoiceItem (IIInvoiceID, IIProfitCenterID, IIStockItemID, IISerialNoTx_N, 
                                 IIQtyIn, IICostPriceCompsTx, IITaxBandIDsTx, IITaxRatesTx, 
                                 IIStockNoTx, IIStockItemTx, IIStockTypeID, IIStockTypeTx, 
                                 IIManufacturerID, IIManufacturerTx, IICustID)

        SELECT 
            IIInvoiceID, 23, 7058, @SerialNo, 
            IIStockTypeID, '-1:1@0', 0, 0,
            'Training.EUCS', 
            (SELECT 'Online Training (SN:'+@SerialNo+')'), 40,'Online Training', 7, 'Company', IICustID
             FROM inserted
             WHERE IIStockTypeID = 1 
               AND IICustID IN (SELECT IICustID
                                FROM T_IIInvoiceItem
                                INNER JOIN T_InInvoice ON InInvoiceID = IIInvoiceID
                                INNER JOIN T_CuCust ON CuCustID = IICustID
                                WHERE IIStockTypeID = 1 AND InTransStatusID = 0
                                GROUP BY IICustID
                                HAVING COUNT(IICustID) = 1)
```

Trigger code is

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SerialTrigger] 
   ON  [dbo].[T_IIInvoiceItem] 
   AFTER INSERT
```

Comment: Please prepare a short, complete repro of this issue.  You will probably discover your error as you do.  If not, add it to your question.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I posted the actual statement.

Comment: My guess is that you're insert statement is checking for the existence of a row in the table. The first time, none exists, and your trigger fires after the row is inserted. The second time, the row already exists in `T_IIIInvoiceItem` and inserts nothing. No insert, no trigger fire. Can you attach your trigger code too? You may want the calling transaction to roll back if the trigger conditions are not met.

Comment: @Xedni many thanks, I added the trigger code too. If I add 2,3,4,5 or more records that meet criteria, it is all fine.
The problem starts only when I add a record where the item does not belong to that StockType=1

Comment: Why is your trigger inserting into the same table that fires the trigger? Your trigger fires when you insert a row into T_IIInvoiceItem and the body does another insert into the same table. This is a pretty good indication that something is a bit off in the design here.

Comment: Add SET NOCOUNT ON as the first statement in the trigger.

Comment: @cloudsafe tnx, it's already missed to paste it here, sorry

Comment: I suspect I need to run a SELECT first in the statement that meets conditions and use the resulting record to populate a new record.
I.E. _SELECT columns WHERE conditions_ and then continue with _INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (...)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (per @DeepDiver):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

--**********************************************   
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
--**********************************************   

DECLARE @SerialNo NVARCHAR(50)

    --    -----------------------------------------------------
    SELECT TOP 1 @SerialNo = SNSerialNoTx 
    FROM T_SNSerialNo 
    WHERE SNStockItemID = 7058 
        AND SNInvoiceID_N IS NULL ;

    --    -----------------------------------------------------
    ; WITH ins
    AS (
        SELECT IIInvoiceID, IIStockTypeID, IICustID
        FROM Inserted
        WHERE IIStockTypeID = 1
            AND IICustID IN (
                SELECT IICustID
                FROM T_IIInvoiceItem
                    INNER JOIN T_InInvoice ON InInvoiceID = IIInvoiceID
                    INNER JOIN T_CuCust ON CuCustID = IICustID
                WHERE IIStockTypeID = 1 
                    AND InTransStatusID = 0
                GROUP BY IICustID
                HAVING COUNT(IICustID) = 1
                )
        )
    --    -----------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO T_IIInvoiceItem (IIInvoiceID, IIProfitCenterID, IIStockItemID, IISerialNoTx_N, 
                                 IIQtyIn, IICostPriceCompsTx, IITaxBandIDsTx, IITaxRatesTx, 
                                 IIStockNoTx, IIStockItemTx, IIStockTypeID, IIStockTypeTx, 
                                 IIManufacturerID, IIManufacturerTx, IICustID)
    SELECT 
        IIInvoiceID
        , 23
        , 7058
        , @SerialNo
        , IIStockTypeID
        , '-1:1@0'
        , 0
        , 0
        , 'Training.EUCS'
        , 'Online Training (SN:'+@SerialNo+')'
        , 40
        ,'Online Training'
        , 7
        , 'Company'
        , IICustID
    FROM ins
```

Comment: tnx a lot, it works as in the syntax is all correct, unfortunately, same situation. As soon as a record that does not meet criteria in the CTE is added, the trigger does not insert a new record next time criteria are met.

Comment: I wonder if it can't see those because they haven't been committed - basically it's waiting for the trigger before it commits them. I edited the trigger to set the transaction isolation level to READ UNCOMMITTED - try that and let us know if it works. The isolation level will reset after the trigger has completed, so it shouldn't cause any problems outside of the trigger.

Comment: tnx a lot for your help. It is, somehow, as you say. The colum IICustID is generated by another trigger and I discovered this only last night. I am now retrieving the CustID from the table higher up in the hierarchy (Invoice tables) because that value is already there and it all works.
As usual, I learn a lot, especially from your latest addition. Thank you.